# Select data if a row does not exists

Tags: mysql

I have several table that are joined. I am trying to select only those that do not have the row inserted.

**Example one**. I select users like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM user_accounts AS ua
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = ua.user_id
    INNER JOIN account_profile_entries AS ape ON ape.user_account_id = ua.id
    INNER JOIN profile_entries AS pe ON pe.id = ape.profile_entry_id
WHERE pe.profile_field_id = 1227 AND pe.value_tinyint = 0;
```

In this query I do have profile field that has 1227 and its value is 0. All ok.

**Example Two**. I also make similar query, but this time value_tinyint = 0:

```
SELECT  *
FROM user_accounts AS ua
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = ua.user_id
    INNER JOIN account_profile_entries AS ape ON ape.user_account_id = ua.id
    INNER JOIN profile_entries AS pe ON pe.id = ape.profile_entry_id
WHERE pe.profile_field_id = 1227 AND pe.value_tinyint = 1;
```

All ok in this case as well.

**Where I am stuck:**

I am stuck when I need to select user_accounts when there is no entry (row) in pe.profile_field_id = 1227
This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_accounts AS ua
WHERE ua.id NOT IN (SELECT u.email AS UserEmail
FROM user_accounts AS ua
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = ua.user_id
    INNER JOIN account_profile_entries AS ape ON ape.user_account_id = ua.id
    INNER JOIN profile_entries AS pe ON pe.id = ape.profile_entry_id
 WHERE pe.profile_field_id = 1227)
```

But this query also returns those users that have the entry 1227.

How can I modify that query to return me only those users that do not have the entry in profile_entries table?

Comment: You'll want a Left join ... or a right join.  Not sure which (which is why I'm not posting in the "answer" box :)

Comment: select id instead of email in your sub query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It  looks like you are selecting email instead of id. Change your query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_accounts AS ua
WHERE ua.id NOT IN (SELECT u.id  
FROM user_accounts AS ua
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = ua.user_id
    INNER JOIN account_profile_entries AS ape ON ape.user_account_id = ua.id
    INNER JOIN profile_entries AS pe ON pe.id = ape.profile_entry_id
WHERE pe.profile_field_id = 1227)
```

Comment: You have pushed me in right direction. I have changed subquery to: SELECT ua.id AS AccountID and it seems to work

Comment: I am glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN operation to the table you don't know if the row exists:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_accounts AS ua
 WHERE ua.id NOT IN 
         (SELECT u.id 
            FROM user_accounts AS ua
                 INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = ua.user_id
                 INNER JOIN account_profile_entries AS ape 
                    ON ape.user_account_id = ua.id
                 LEFT JOIN profile_entries AS pe 
                    ON pe.id = ape.profile_entry_id
                       AND pe.profile_field_id = 1227)
```

Notice that I also moved the `pe.profile_field_id = 1227` to the JOIN section because if you use the LEFT JOIN operation and have a join on the left joined table if is not a left join anymore.

You also need to change the column on your subquery to ID since it is what you are comparing it to.

Comment: I have run it, and I am still getting the user account back that does not have it. I would really like to use the left join solution :)

Comment: Ok, so the problem was just the wrong column first mentioned in the @isaace answer. Not the left join.